# Defining custom tags in XSLT transformation

Tags: php, xml, xslt, rss, xslt-1.0

I use php DOMDocument for XSLT transforming one XML to another and i need to use additional tag - **mytag** in resulting document tag like

```
<mytag:full-text>...</mytag:full-text>
```

to define this tag i tryed construction like this:

```
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="mytag" result-prefix="mytag"/>
```

and so i get an error

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Namespace prefix mytag on full-text is not defined
```

what's i am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be using "tag" to mean both "namespace prefix" and "element". The former especially is not accurate. I think you will make your work a lot easier for yourself, and for communicating with others for help, if you learn some basic XML terminology. E.g. see http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/effectivexml/chapters/00.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is a complete code example how to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:mytag="my:tag" exclude-result-prefixes="mytag">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b">
  <b>
    <mytag:full-text>Some full-text here</mytag:full-text>
  </b>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<a><b/></a>
```

**the wanted, correct result (the new element added under `b`) is produced:**

```
<a>
   <b>
      <mytag:full-text xmlns:mytag="my:tag">Some full-text here</mytag:full-text>
   </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  xmlns:mytag="some_namespace" to the root of your XSLT so you get something like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:mytag="some_namespace">
```

Comment: this error has disapeared, but now i get attribute xmlns:mytag="http://..." on every root tag in resulting xml document

Comment: That is expected behavior. For your output to be valid XML the namespace prefix for 'mytag' must be declared somewhere in your XML document, otherwise 'mytag' has no meaning. You can manually add it to the root node of your output if you don't want it to be added to all the child nodes.

Comment: @shershen: I don't know what you mean by "root tag" - possibly the start tag of the outermost element? Depending on what you mean, you could use `exclude-result-prefixes="*"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element. Another question is, why do you want to avoid having xmlns:mytag declarations on certain elements? It shouldn't hurt anything, and some declarations are necessary if you're going to use namespaces. If you have namespace declarations that you think are unnecessary, and are not solved by exclude-result-prefixes, please give details.